# How to get the tag number from an imageview in scrollview?

Tags: xcode, tags, touch, imageview, scrollview

I'm getting trouble with getting tag number from imageview.
I added UIGestureRecognizer to each imageviews in scrollview, and tried to get the tag number from touched view.
After I touched the image, nothing happend.
Is my code wrong? Please help me.

```
    // to add images
    for (int i = 0; i < app.arrPhotoList.count; i++) {

        UIImageView *subImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        subImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        subImg.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        subImg.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
        subImg.tag = i;
        subImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UIGestureRecognizer *singleTab = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTag:)];
        [subImg addGestureRecognizer:singleTab];


        /////// add img to array of imageviews/////////////
        NSString *imgName = [[app.arrPhotoList objectAtIndex:i]stringByAppendingString:@"_thumb.jpg"];
        subImg.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgName];
        [scrImgView addSubview:subImg];
}


-(void) imageTag:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"you selected tag number is : %d",sender.view.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIGestureRecognizer` and also set delegate. For any further information you may see about [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTab = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTag:)];
        singleTab.delegate=self;
        [subImg addGestureRecognizer:singleTab];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: By the way, I'm getting warning message on singleTap.delegate = self; which is 'Passing *const_strong to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UIGestureRecognizer>' I think it is because of delegate type is UIGestureRecognizer. is there any way to solve the warning message?

Comment: You have to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in yourClass.h file like @interface yourClass : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Comment: Thank you so much again! i got lots of things from you today ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
UIGestureRecognizer *singleTab = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTag:)];
```

to this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTab = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTag:)];
```

HTH.